# Difference between function with object and direct object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-grid

I wrote custom binding element for kendo grid in knockoutjs. I wandered by facing this problem. Can any one tell me the difference `statement 1` and `statement 2`

```
var newObj = { obj1 : 'One', obj2: 'Two', obj3: true, obj4: [ 'One','Two' ] }
//***Statement 1
return newObj; // By this statement am getting an error
//******
//****** Statement 2
var result = function(){ return newObj; }
return result; // By this statement program is working
```

//******

Comment: result is a function, newObj is an object. They are different types so that's why the first one is not working,

Answer (score 1):

The calling code expect a function that returns the object...

The code could do a lot of clever stuff to accept both but is a lot simpler if it have a simple and clear interface. Obey that interface.

An example.

"Someone gifted you a new shirt."

You can do the clever think and look it the gift is wrapped in a nice gift box or not and take the proper action. (1) If the gift is wrapped then unwrap it and wear it. (2) If it is not wrapped just wear it.

To make the interface of the function you are using (or passing a callback, or some function you are using ahead in the code) they opted to not do the clever thing (that can be difficult to program some times) then is like it someone gave you a unwrapped shirt but you expected it to be wrapped so you just tear the shirt apart trying to unwrap it (but it is not wrapped).

**Summary:**

1. **Read the relevant documentation for the library you are using;**
2. **Obey the interface for the library you are using;**

Answer (score 1):

If you really are using knockout as your tags suggest... I am going to take a stab in the dark and say that you were probably looking for something like this:

Notice that newObj is an observable an you access the object with newObj()

```js
    var model = function(){
      var newObj = ko.observable({ obj1 : 'One', obj2: 'Two', obj3: true, obj4: [ 'One','Two' ] })
      //***Statement 1
      
      function alertObj1(){
        //Notice i access object with () here. It is an observable is essentially a function.
        alert(newObj().obj1);
      }
      
      return {
        newObj: newObj,
        alertObj1: alertObj1 
      }
    }



    ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: newObj">
    <div data-bind="text: obj1"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: obj2"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: obj3"></div>
    <h1>foreach</h1>
    <div data-bind="foreach: obj4">
      <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: alertObj1" >Alert Prop Obj1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.

Actually user: Sxntk comment is helped to think it in different way. By small research I came to know that kendo accepting function, that function return the object.

And Finally specially thanks to Prusse and 4imble. Because of you people I got two new things. All your explanations are correct but `sxntk` answer is suitable for my question.